# Raspberry Pi not able to receive and view stream from another Pi using gStreamer

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera, gstreamer

I've got a double Pi setup. One 3b and one 4. The 4 is setup with the 7" raspberry pi screen. The 3b is setup with two cameras. I'll name these "sender" (3b) and "player" (4).

I'm trying to use gstreamer to send low latency video from the sender to the reciever. I've found and used this command on the sender:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! \
    'video/x-raw, width=352, height=288, framerate=25/1' ! \
    videoconvert ! \
    x264enc pass=qual quantizer=20 tune=zerolatency ! \
    rtph264pay ! \
    multiudpsink clients="10.0.0.200:5600,10.0.0.178:5600"
```

And using this code on the receiver:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5600 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```

So first I tested the receiver command on my Windows PC and it works flaweless. Sub 100ms delay and everything.

Now I test this on the receiver pi 4 and I get this:

```
pi@receiver4:~ $ gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5600 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
```

It stops here then I start the sender and the following happens:

```
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:src: caps = application/x-rtp, payload=(int)96, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Depay:rtph264depay0.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp, payload=(int)96, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264

/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Depay:rtph264depay0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, codec_data=(buffer)017a000dffe1001b677a000dbcb202c12d80a506060640000003004000000ca3c50a9201000668ebc1b2c8b0, level=(string)1.3, profile=(string)high-4:2:2
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/avdec_h264:avdec_h264-0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, codec_data=(buffer)017a000dffe1001b677a000dbcb202c12d80a506060640000003004000000ca3c50a9201000668ebc1b2c8b0, level=(string)1.3, profile=(string)high-4:2:2
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/avdec_h264:avdec_h264-0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)Y42B, width=(int)352, height=(int)288, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)25/1
Redistribute latency...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
../libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(3127): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
Execution ended after 0:00:03.494063865
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

So why is this not streaming on the raspberry pi screen as it does on my windows screen? I tested with the test video src and I get a window with the expected output:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! autovideosink
```

[image]

Comment: Q1: Have you tried with `udpsink` instead of `multiudpsink`? Q2: In your tests, have you tried *first* opening the player on the pi, instead of your PC, which I assume is the other udp host specified?

Comment: You may try adding `rtpjitterbuffer` plugin between udpsrc and rtph264depay. This plugin has a latency property, default value would be 2000 ms.

Comment: @ChristianFritz Yes, I found out about multiudpsink later so I could test on my windows PC aswell as the Pi. But I used only udpsink first. @SeB: That made it crash the same way.  `ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: Internal data stream error.` Just for clarity the problem is that the "receiver" is not able to show the stream. But my windows PC is. Guessing it is some RPI things my receiving command does not work with.

Comment: @ChristianFritz: And Q2 yes I tried the Pi first, PC first, Sender first THEN receiver e.t.c. The PC Always works no matter how i start it.

Comment: Try adding h264parse plugin between rtph264depay and decoder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this as sender:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc do-timestamp=1 is-live=1 ! video/x-raw, width=352, height=288, framerate=25/1 ! videoconvert ! x264enc pass=qual quantizer=20 tune=zerolatency insert-vui=1 key-int-max=16 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=<target_host_IP_v4_or_v6> port=5004 -ev
```

and this as receiver:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc address=<same_IP_v4_or_v6_address> port=5004 ! application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=H264,clock-rate=90000 ! rtpjitterbuffer latency=300 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink -v
```

In case the network between both RPi is wifi, you may also try disabling updsink `auto-multicast` property.

Comment: SeB! You're the man. Instead of "videotestsrc" and the do-timestamp and is-live I added the `v4l2src device=/dev/video0` and it worked. Atleast I have a video now. Now I'll just figure out how to get best possible video resolution and best possible latency (sub 100ms). Both are going to be ethernet. Thanks for this! I've been on this for a week now and not got anything working. Really dont understand this but still learning so you saved me a lot!

Comment: Seems like all I missed was the "videoconvert". Running my original command and adding the "videoconvert" it works: `gst-launch-1.0 -e udpsrc port=5600 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink`

Comment: Sub 100 ms with a 25 fps framerate in H264 may not be feasible...You have have one frame being recorded on camera side and another one being displayed on monitor...so only 2 frames for processing...Video encoding use temporal redundancy that may use P frame or B -frames for prediction, so not good for low latency. If you need lower latency, probably a higher fps would help..or try MJPG encoding that just needs one frame for encoding...

Comment: About videoconvert, I added that after seeing your decoder was using format Y42B...this may be the root cause. Glad to see you've now a working pipeline.

Comment: I found this working with it seems to be sub 300ms using the csi camera instead of the USB camera:  `libcamera-vid --width 800 --height 600 -t 0 -g 300 -n --inline -o - | gst-launch-1.0 fdsrc fd=0 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! multiudpsink clients="10.0.0.200:5600,10.0.0.178:5600"`. A quick check by taking a picture of the viewer pi while camera is on a stopwatch shows 58s 60/100th on the timer and 58s 30/100th on the viewer so 300ms. That is manageable to operate a underwater ROV.

Comment: Tuning this I might get 100ms (lower res/fps). But I'll see. Using the webcam is prolly too slow as it does not give raw h264 packages as the pi cam. Needs less pipeline :D Also I'm currently over 2.4ghz wifi, so when on ethernet this 300ms prolly goes lower.